# Posting wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a code in php to update a table.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $Result['id']; ?>" readonly /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $Result['studentid']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="subjectid" value="<?php echo $Result['subjectid']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="marks" value="<?php echo $Result['marks']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo $Result['term']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo $Result['year']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo $Result['rank']; ?>" /></div></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Cancel" OnClick="window.location='<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>';" /></td>
<td></td>
</form>
```

The error I am having is that it posts the value it received and not the changed one (Changed while editing on the page)

Comment: that onclick handler is superfluous, just let it submit

Comment: Show your php code also. Or try to change your button in submit and write php_self in your form action.

Comment: i have inserted my entire code

Comment: Why are you doing an output buffer just to assign the `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: @Rasclatt it is easier to use $id than $_POST['id']

Comment: But why not just do `$id = $_POST['id'];`? Also, under the `if($action == "update")` is that where the values aren't changing?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes they are not changing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your edit page from where you can update you data . i have used my database connect firstly you have to change database and table name.

And you should pass `id` of that row in form of query string like `edit.php?id=12`.

```
<?php 
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
        mysql_select_db("test");
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {

         $id=$_POST['id'];
         $st_id=$_POST['studentid'];
         $sub_id=$_POST['subjectid'];
         $marks=$_POST['marks'];
         $term=$_POST['term'];
         $year=$_POST['year'];
         $rank=$_POST['rank'];
            $sql="UPDATE  `test`.`user` SET  `st_id` =  '$st_id',
                `sub_id` =  '$sub_id',
                `mark` =  '$marks',
                `term` =  '$term',
                `year` =  '$year',
                `rank` =  '$rank' WHERE  `user`.`id` =`$id`";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
    $result=mysql_query("select * from user where id=$id");
    $Result=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </html>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $Result['id']; ?>" readonly /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $Result['st_id']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="subjectid" value="<?php echo $Result['sub_id']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="marks" value="<?php echo $Result['mark']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo $Result['term']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo $Result['year']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo $Result['rank']; ?>" /></div></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Cancel" OnClick="window.location='<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>';" /></td>
    <td></td>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Error Save [Unknown column '12' in 'where clause']

Comment: I have checked  @Bhaamp it is working simply you have send id in href when you click on edit button like <a href="edit.php?id=12"><button name="edit">Edit</button>

Comment: It worked. Thanks my mistake was that the values where in backticks